# Solution of motion in hamiltonian formalism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, differential-equations

I have these canonical equations: 
$$\dot p = - \alpha pq$$
$$ \dot q =\frac{1}{2} \alpha q^2$$

I have to find $q(t)$ and p$(t)$, considering initial conditions $p_0$ and $q_0$.

I thought to simply integrate with respect time both members of the equations, but something must be wrong because the solutions are:$$q(t)=\frac{q_0}{1- \frac{1}{2} \alpha q_0 (t-t_0)}$$ $$p(t)=p_0[1-\frac{1}{2} \alpha q_0 (t-t_0)]$$ and I don't know how obtain them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $q$ equation is a separable ODE that can be directly integrated.  To do this, note that it can be written as
$$
  \frac{dq}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\alpha q^2
$$
so that multiplying both sides by $dt$ and integrating from $t_0$ to $t$ gives
$$
  \frac{2}{\alpha}\int_{q_0}^{q(t)}\frac{1}{q^2}dq = \int_{t_0}^t dt'
$$
which after integration implies
$$
  -\frac{2}{\alpha}\left[\frac{1}{q(t)}-\frac{1}{q_0}\right] = t-t_0
$$
next, solve for $q(t)$.  Plug this back into the first equation, again separate variables and integrate to obtain $p(t)$.

Hope that helps!

Physics Rocks.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I've just begun to study ODE... could you write the initial steps to follow for arriving to the first expression that you have written? thanks again!

Comment: All right I included more details.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you!! I have a problem (the last problem! :D): I haven't understood what I have to plug back and where. If I consider that $H=E=\frac{1}{2}\alpha p q^2$ and that $2E=\alpha p q^2=\alpha p_0 q_0^2$ and I plug back q(t) in this relation, I obtain the correct result for p(t). But if I plug back it in $\dot p=..$, I obtain a wrong result (p(t) is a logarithmic function... ). What's wrong?

Comment: Plug back into your first equation for $p$.  When you separate variables there, the integral over $t$ will also give a log, and the logs should drop out in the end.

Comment: I'm so grateful!! :)

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Comment: Hi, joshphysics! :) I have made again this exercise after months and I have found an aspect that I understimated and so I have asked a new question.. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66621/hamiltonian-equations-can-i-divide-a-solution-of-motion-for-a-constant/66623?noredirect=1#comment134239_66623 could you help me again? many thanks!